# Why Apache CollectionUtils.containsAny does not require Collection of same type

Tags: java

Why containsAny method of Apache CollectionUtils does not strictly require two list with same generic type? In my experience I always have to check collections of same type and it would help me to have a strict type parameters. Is this a way to give developers more flexibility or is there another reason?

Comment: Can you provide some code? According online documentation it should be possible.

Comment: Probably for the same reason that `Collection.contains()` takes an `Object` and not a `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the only method on the element types required by the method is `Object.equals`, which, obviously, is implemented by all types. I.e. the method doesn't require the types have any commonality other than `Object`, so there is no need for the element types to be the same.

If you prefer, you can define your own wrapper method to enforce the requirement that the element types are the same:

```
public static <T> boolean containsAny(Collection<T> coll1, Collection<T> coll2) {
    return CollectionsUtils.containsAny(coll1, coll2);
}
```